my browser is Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code invalid-first-character-of-tag-name
Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code invalid-first-character-of-tag-name
 at C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/index.html:1:4
1  |  ��<!DOCTYPE html>
   |     ^
2  |  <html lang="en">
3  |  
 at C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/index.html:1:4
    at handleParseError (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:35142:9)
    at Parser.onParseError (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:35067:7)
    at Tokenizer._err (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:1155:89)
    at Tokenizer._stateTagOpen (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:1983:26)
    at Tokenizer._callState (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:1534:22)
    at Tokenizer._runParsingLoop (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:1179:22)
    at Tokenizer.write (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:1204:14)
    at Parser.parse (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:4886:26)
    at parse (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-D-7KCb9p.js:7957:19)
    at traverseHtml (file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/learn_tailwindcss_windows/node_modules/vite/dist

tried creating a config file for vite but still not working

Look at the error: there's 2 characters before your <!DOCTYPE starts. It's possible that that is a so-called BOM that some old editors embed in text files. If thats the case for you, switch to a better editor. Otherwise: get rid of the garbage before the DOCTYPE tag
